# Hadoop FileSystem deletes source file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I upload a file from local PC to hdfs using:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
boolean deleteSrc = true;
String destFile = "/user/admin/my.csv";
fs.copyFromLocalFile(deleteSrc,new Path(inputFile), new Path(destFile));
```

This results in the file being deleted from loca storage. So, the copy is actually a 'move'.
How do I just upload a copy of the loca file?

Comment: I think `deleteSrc` should be set to `false` if you don't want to delete from local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note you are setting first parameter of `copyFromLocalFile` call to true, this cause local file getting deleted. If you want to retain local file, set  `deleteSrc` to `false`.

Following are details of `copyFromLocalFile` method.

> ```
> public void copyFromLocalFile(boolean delSrc,
>                               boolean overwrite,
>                               Path[] srcs,
>                               Path dst)
>                        throws IOException
> ```
>
> The src files are on the local disk. Add it to the filesystem at the given dst name. delSrc indicates if the source should be removed
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> delSrc - whether to delete the src
> overwrite - whether to overwrite an existing file
> srcs - array of paths which are source
> dst - path
> ```
>
> **Throws:**
>
> ```
> IOException - IO failure
> ```

You may also refer [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile-boolean-boolean-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path:A-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-).